# In Eldritch Horror, do epic monsters have to be encountered before non epic monsters?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The guide by The Esoteric Order of Gamers says

> If you are on a space with 1 or more monsters, you must resolve a single combat encounter against each monster there, one at a time, in the order of your choice. Each non-epic monster must be encountered before each epic monster.

I'm not familiar with this source, so is there a definitive reference in the quick reference or rulebook or some officially released errata that confirms this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is taken from the rules of the Forsaken Lore expansion pack. Those rules say:

---

**Additional Rules**
The *Forsaken Lore* expansion adds new rules as described below.

**Combat Encounters**
During the Encounter Phase, an investigator must encounter each non-Epic Monster on his space before encountering each Epic Monster on his space.

---

Do note however, that this is the opposite of this question title. Epic Monsters should be encountered last, not first, according to the expansion rule set.